# How does includes work in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, include, visibility

In my folder I have a small `version.cpp` file with the following structure:

```
#include "thelibr/version.h"

const int major = MAJOR;
const int minor = MINOR;
```

I cannot understand what this code does and how is it used by the remaining part of the code (stored in other files of the same directory).

First, I understand that the code sets values of two variables (`major` and `minor`) but what is not clear to me is where the values of `MAJOR` and `MINOR` are set. Are they set in `thelibr/version.h`.

Second, it is also not clear to me when the above given lines of the code are executed. They are not put in any method that could potentially be called from other methods coded in other files. So, how these lines can be called?

Third, I see that string `version` is not present in any other file from the same directory. Does it mean that none of these file uses the code stored in the `version.cpp`. Shouldn't we include `version.h` file somewhere in other file to be able to use the code from the `version.cpp`?

Fourth, if we set the values of `major` and `minor` variables in the `version.cpp`, will these variables be visible somewhere else? It wonders me since we do not use any words like `global` or `external`.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have a module system like Python where pure symbols may be exported and their values used in another source file. Instead it has header files: The contents of `thelibr/version.h` are essentially copy-pasted in place of the `#include` line. Anything inside that file is processed as if it were written out in the `version.cpp` file.

To export from one file to another (or to create libraries which can be interpreted by the linker or dynamic loader), use `extern` storage, which is the default for many things.

Deciding what is visible from one `.cpp` file to the next is rather complicated, but as a rule you cannot share compile-time values such as the version number; you can only share access to runtime objects such as the `int`s which store the version number.

To use `major` and `minor` from another `.cpp` file, you could declare in `version.h`:

```
extern const int major;
extern const int minor;
```

And then `#include "thelibr/version.h"` from the other file.

Comment: IMHO if you're providing an example you might as well go all the way and show a sample version.h, version.cpp. Otherwise I fear your answer might actually contribute to OP's confusion.

Comment: @busy_wait What else should I add? Aside from the header guards, which I presume he already has, this particular example seems to be covered. The problem is the many other kinds of cases, like `inline` functions, `static` objects, and `static` members. To be honest it sounds like OP isn't really prepared to dive into C++.

Comment: I think the question about #includes applies equally well to the subset of C++ that looks just like C. IMO the most important point should be to illustrate the difference between sharing a #define via a header file vs. sharing a declaration for a variable that is actually defined in one of the implementation files. Just my two cents. I don't want to undercut your otherwise good answer by writing my own.

Comment: @busy_wait There's no undercutting on SO, don't hesitate to contribute. On second thought, I've made this "community wiki" so you can edit it without making your own, new answer. But neither of us will get points for upvotes.